# ASP.Net MVC3 SQL Connection String

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string, appharbor

I am creating an app on APPHARBOR and I have an entity model for querying the SQL server. The following String is givving me error:

```
<add name="TraxzDBEntities" 
           connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;
           provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
           provider connection string='Data Source=d5d3955e-1183-4e10-8892-9f9d005af0a8.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;
           User ID=**; 
           Password=**;
           Initial Catalog=dbd5d3955e11834e1088929f9d005af0a8;Integrated Security=true;
           MultipleActiveResultSets=True'"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is the stack trace:
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5110868
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +112
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings) +309
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +52
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel() +10
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +265
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
   Traxz.Models.TraxzRepository.getListOfUserExerciseSessions(Guid userID) in d:\temp\lhvy3m2t.j0d\input\Traxz\Models\TraxzRepository.cs:77
   Traxz.Controllers.ExerciseSessionController.listSessions(Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 SessionID) in d:\temp\lhvy3m2t.j0d\input\Traxz\Controllers\ExerciseSessionController.cs:34
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +164
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8963149
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I wasted numerous hours on this, and idk what is wrong.. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is seemingly some other connect string being used here. Are you setting a connect string in code as well?
in your asp.net mvc project what are all the connect strings in the web.config? Just the above?

Search your entire solution for the word "server"

Comment: Agreed, I had this happen and it ended up being a different connection string being referenced by the designer.

Comment: Well i have read some documentation on appharbor and it appears that they force you to construct a dynamic connection string-- but I have tested this string and it queries the hosted sql server correctly.

Comment: Then you are leaving out important details. What is this dynamic connection string? I would venture to say it doesnt work correctly by the error above.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Adam's suggestion (which is probably the answer), in your code snippet you don't have a `;` after `Password=**` (maybe you do in the real code though).  And you are also using both username and password and `Integrated Security=true;` which doesn't make sense to me since `Integrated Security=true;` means to use the currently logged on user.

Comment: i tried deleting Integrated Security=true; -- however this has no effect.